# Basis-Transformation-Matrix applied onto basis vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'd like to ask about the following Basis-Transformation-Matrix $T$ between $B$ and $\tilde{B}$:
$$B=T\tilde{B}$$
Why is it that when we want to transform the basis vectors from one basis to the other we use \tilde{B}\tilde{B} as in:
$$T^{-1}\cdot\bf{e}_n=\tilde{\bf{e}}_n$$
But when transforming vectors we use:
$$T\cdot\bf{v}=\tilde{\bf{v}}$$

Thanks for any answers!